# Tensorflow: lookup tensor at index in timestream

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training an RNN where I need to use an index to lookup the value in another part of the example's timestream

```
v = tf.constant([
    [[.1, .2], [.3, .4]],  # timestream 1 values
    [[.6, .5], [.7, .8]]   # timestream 2 values
])
ixs = tf.constant([
    [1, 0], # indices into timestream 1 values
    [0, 1]  # indices into timestream 2 values
])
```

I'm looking for an op that will do the lookup and replace the indices with the tensor values and yield:

```
[
    [[.3, .4], [.1, .2]],
    [[.6, .5], [.7, .8]]
]
```

tf.gather and tf.gather_nd sound like they might be the right path, but I don't really understand the results I'm getting from them.

```
v_at_ix = tf.gather(v, ixs, axis=-1)
sess.run(v_at_ix)
array([[[[0.2, 0.1],
         [0.1, 0.2]],
        [[0.4, 0.3],
         [0.3, 0.4]]],
       [[[0.5, 0.6],
         [0.6, 0.5]],
        [[0.8, 0.7],
         [0.7, 0.8]]]], dtype=float32)

v_at_ix = tf.gather_nd(v, ixs)
sess.run(v_at_ix)
array([[0.6, 0.5],
       [0.3, 0.4]], dtype=float32)
```

Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tf.gather** can only obtain slices based on a specified axis, and its indices are juxtaposed. In `v_at_ix = tf.gather(v, ixs, axis=-1)`:

`1` in `[1, 0]` represents `[[[.2],[.4]],[[.5],[.8]]]` in `v`.

`0` in `[1, 0]` represents `[[[.1],[.3]],[[.6],[.7]]]` in `v`.

`0` in `[0, 1]` represents `[[[.1],[.3]],[[.6],[.7]]]` in `v`.

`1` in `[0, 1]` represents `[[[.2],[.4]],[[.5],[.8]]]` in `v`.

**tf.gather_nd** is able to obtain slices at specified indices, and its indices are progressive. In `v_at_ix = tf.gather_nd(v, ixs)`:

`1` in `[1, 0]` represents `[[.6, .5], [.7, .8]]` in `v`.

`0` in `[1, 0]` represents `[.6, .5]` in `[[.6, .5], [.7, .8]]`.

`0` in `[0, 1]` represents `[[.1, .2], [.3, .4]]` in `v`.

`1` in `[0, 1]` represents `[.3, .4]` in `[[.1, .2], [.3, .4]]`.

So we need is `[[[0,1],[0,0]],[[1,0],[1,1]]]` when we use `tf.gather_nd`. It can be composed of `[[0,0],[1,1]]` and `[[1,0],[0,1]]`. The former is a duplicate line number, and the latter is `ixs`. So we can do it

```
ixs_row = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(tf.range(v.shape[0]),-1),multiples=[1,v.shape[1]])
ixs = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(ixs_row,-1),tf.expand_dims(ixs,-1)],axis=-1)
v_at_ix = tf.gather_nd(v,ixs)
```